# Hide ProgressBar once RecyclerView.setAdapter is done Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

For an app i'm creating I have a RecyclerView that gets filled with data from a Firebase Database. This RecyclerView is also in a fragment that's used in a Viewpager. All and all I am able to make it work, but what I notice is, is that on the first run it takes a while for the fragment to show it's content in the RecyclerView, so I wanted to add a ProgressBar to it as an Asynchronous Task.

**My Task:**

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            loadColleagueData();
            mListener = initRealTime();
            mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mUserList, getActivity());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mProgressLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Now this works actually. The ProgressBar gets shown and also is hidden again once it's done. But the problem is, is that it's done in such a short time that it's not visible. So I only know that it works because of debugging. What still takes a while is the RecyclerView actually showing the content.

So what I guess my problem is, is that not so much getting the data from the Database is the thing that takes a while, just more setting the Adapter to the RecyclerView and showing it's content is the thing that takes a while.

Now from what I understood is, is that it's not possible to set the adapter in the `doInBackground` since you can't do anything with the views outside of the main ui thread. So I was wondering if there is a way to hide the ProgressBar only once the content is visible in my RecyclerView?

(If this is a duplicate question i'm awfully sorry, my search on the internet did not manage to help me)

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the FirebaseDatabase callbacks, you don't need to use an AsyncTask for this. If you what to listen for single event, that means that you just want to download the data, then use this:

```
        mProgressLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DatabaseReference node = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("your_node");
        node.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                loadColleagueData();
                mListener = initRealTime();
                mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mUserList, getActivity());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mProgressLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want your Adapter to be allways up-to-date you can attach listeners to that specific nodes using addChildEventListener() or addValueEventListener() ([docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)). Or you can use this grate library, you just need to copy one file:

https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview